# OrientDB java API with tinkerpop 3

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop3

what is the best API for Orient to Java for 3.0 snapshot?and how do I 
1. connect
2. execute CRUD 
3. execute native queries (SQL/Javascript).

Started with orientdb-gremlin but not yet upto speed, so wanted to check with community.

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of db connection and execution of an SQL query:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String DBname="Test";
    String currentPath="remote:localhost/"+DBname;

    OServerAdmin serverAdmin;
    try {
        serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin(currentPath).connect("root", "root"); 
        if(serverAdmin.existsDatabase()){  

            OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph(currentPath); 

            Iterable<Vertex> result=g.command(new OCommandSQL("select from Person")).execute(); 
            for(Vertex v:result){ 
                String rid=v.getId().toString();
                String name=v.getProperty("name");
                String surname=v.getProperty("surname");
                System.out.println(rid + " " + name + " " + surname);  
            }

            g.shutdown(); 

        }
        serverAdmin.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }   
}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Michela